# variable selection in r using knn

Tags: r, knn, roc

I have a data frame (df) of 72 observations and 592 variable with one factor class variable (total of 593 variables i.e dim(df) = 72 593). I am looking for a way to select 7 variables (including the class variable) using Receiver Operating Characteristics (ROC) for selection of the optimum k value. I want to use these seven variables for analysis using graphical models but I don't want to select the variables at random. I want my selection to be statistically justified.

What I would like to see as my result is something like:

> Variables V23, V120, V230, V333, V496, V585, V593 were selected based on the highest value of ROC.

I.e I want to perform classification and selection of the "best" predicted variables of high accuracy so that I can used these variables for graphical modelling.

I have tried using the caret package but I don't know how to manipulate it to select variables (columns) of high accuracy which can be used for other analysis.

Thanks guys. Am sure someone understood me.

Thanks.

kutex.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
library(pROC)

#' Select the N top variables with ROC analysis
#' @param response the class variable name
#' @param predictors the variables names from which to select
#' @param data must contain the predictors as columns
#' @param n the number of 
select.top.N.ROC <- function(response, predictors, data, n) {
    n <- min(n, length(predictors))
    aucs <- sapply(predictors, function(predictor) {
        auc(data[[response]], data[[predictor]])
    })
    return(predictors[order(aucs, decreasing=TRUE)][1:n])
}

top.variables <- select.top.N.ROC("class", paste("V", 1:593, sep=""), myDataFrame, 7)
cat(paste("Variables", paste(top.variables, collapse=", "), "were selected based on the highest value of ROC. "))
```

As with any univariate feature selection method, you may select 7 fully correlated variables that won't give you any additional information, so selecting V23 would have been sufficient. For multivariate datasets, you should consider using a multivariate feature selection method instead.